# How to stop subscription after receiving n number of messages in mqtt's subscribe bash?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt

How to stop subscription after receiving n number of messages in mqtt's subscribe bash?

Comment: Your going to have supply a lot more information if you want us to help. What app are you using (mosquitto_sub)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `mosquitto_sub`

The following is taken from the [man page](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html):

> -C
>
> Disconnect and exit the program immediately after the given count of
>   messages have been received. This may be useful in shell scripts
>   where on a single status value is required, for example.

e.g.

```
$ mosquitto_sub -t 'foo/bar' -C 1 > one_message.txt
```

This will subscribe to topic `foo/bar` and wait for a single message which it will store in the file `one_message.txt`